# google analytics js not loading

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am having problems with ga.js not loading sometimes. In firebug it just shows a connection being tried but it sometimes never makes it. This happens more than half the time and I cant believe that googles servers are not serving the scripts. In fact I can load the ga.js in my browser and it loads fine every time, so why does it not load when being called from my page?

Could it be that other scripts are loading before ga.js and stopping it from loading (ga.js loads last)??

Cheers

Ke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, scripts can block download of other resources (not just other scripts either).

Description:
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/

A solution:
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/